# Refresh div vs entire page on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, page-refresh, onresize

I have some code that doesn't refresh when the window gets resized...so if it's big even if I have the size set to 100% it doesn't auto-adjust. The original solution I thought about was to refresh the content, which definitely works, however on mobile every time I scroll the page up and down the page gets refreshed - so I can't even browse the site. It's more of a nuance than a fix. I was hoping there was a way to tweak what I'm using to just refresh the div instead of the entire page.

The div code I have looks like:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/woodsyhollow" data-width="800" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false"></div>
```

I can throw an ID on the div, so if there was a way to target this specific div, I think that's all I need.

The code for the refresh looks like:

```
<script>
    window.onresize = function(){ location.reload(); }
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: How did you write your css that it doesn't auto-adjust?

Comment: `.fb-page { width: 100%; }`. My guess is, it's the way Facebook generates their content, not really sure. What happens is if it's 400px then I resize the window it stays 400px when it should change based on the windows size, but it's like it's stuck unless I refresh the page.

Comment: Does your FB plugin inject some markup, right? If that's the case you could try setting the width on that level

Comment: I only have the code I shared, not sure how I can change what Facebook renders with the code that’s available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries for a simple fix .
Try something like;

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
div data {
width: 200px
```

Comment: Hey there, I tried this, but it doesn’t seem to change anything. The div doesn’t change to 200px when the screen size is under 600px. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: you can try calling the class so inside the media screen try 
.fb-page {

Comment: That's what my original css looks like, it's like the way FB works is it only generates the iframe once and then it stays that way unless the page is refreshed. So, if it's 600px, it stays 600px regardless of how big or small the window is. If it starts 200px, then it stays 200px, etc. That's why I was thinking of refreshing just the specific div and not the whole page.

Comment: Have you tried flexbox?

Comment: Yes, that's actually how my columns are setup, it's a flexbox column. I thought I could just do flex-basis: 100%, but that didn't work either. I think a page refresh needs to be in there somewhere and I don't think CSS can do that